# How to save log output in a file in linux

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, logging

I need to create an accessible log file in our linux server.
A java program is used to create a log.

In my console

```
Sep 11, 2014 3:03:05 PM com.gsis.bom.Log appLog
SEVERE: test 1
Sep 11, 2014 3:03:06 PM com.gsis.bom.Log appLog
INFO: test 2
Sep 11, 2014 3:03:06 PM com.gsis.bom.Log appLog
INFO: test 3
```

But this messages should be saved in a file in linux. For e.g. `/home/logs`
How can I do it?

THANK YOU

**EDIT**

```
LogManager lm = LogManager.getLogManager();
          Logger logger;
          FileHandler fh = new FileHandler("log_test.txt");

          logger = Logger.getLogger("LoggingExample1");

          lm.addLogger(logger);
          logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
          fh.setFormatter(new XMLFormatter());

          logger.addHandler(fh);
          logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "test 1");
          logger.log(Level.INFO, "test 2");
          logger.log(Level.INFO, "test 3");
          fh.close();
```

This is the code that I am using. Ok I can see it in my console. **But I need the messages to be saved in a file. For example at /home/logs/log.txt in our linux server**

Comment: Use a Logging framework like Log4J.

Comment: http://www.slf4j.org/

Comment: Use output redirection operator with your java program. e.g. `your_java_prog_binary > /home/logs.txt`

Comment: Hi @AbimaranKugathasan, do you have sample code? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use class something like below,

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class CreateLog{

    static Logger logEntry = Logger.getLogger(
                  CreateLog.class.getName());

    public void testLog(){
        logEntry.info("some information message");
        logEntry .error("some error message");
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my question and put some codes. I need a code that will save it to our linux server

Comment: As far as log4j is concerned, you have to specify key(log4j.appender.FILE.File) for file name and path in configuration file(log4j.properties)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are using [java.util.logging](/questions/tagged/java.util.logging). In that case, you can add an appender programmatically as in the following example.

```
// the maximum number of bytes to write to any one file
int limit = 5 * 1024 * 1024; 

// the number of files to use
int count = 10;              

Handler handler = new FileHandler("/home/logs/log_test.txt", limit, count);
Logger.getLogger("").addHandler(handler);
```

You may want to see [Where does java.util.logging.Logger store their log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025691/where-does-java-util-logging-logger-store-their-log), [Java logging opening "too many" logfiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382679/java-logging-opening-too-many-logfiles) and [Java Logging API generating empty log files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641633/java-logging-api-generating-empty-log-files/16643903#16643903)

Comment: Im going to try this @Paul Vargas

Comment: It's not working. I've got an exception `Exception thrown: java.io.IOException: Couldn't get lock for /home/logs/log_test.txt
java.io.IOException: Couldn't get lock for /home/logs/log_test.txt`

Comment: @user3264438 See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111525/java-io-ioexception-couldnt-get-lock-for